# Switch to external monitor by default when it is plugged in

Tags: nvidia, external-monitor, vga

I have Thinkpad T510 with NVidia videocard and an external monitor connected via VGA.

I have a following usage pattern:

- Turn on the laptop in the docking station below the desk
- Take it out, open, wait while it loads
- Log in, launch nvidia-settings, set the resolution of the external monitor to "Auto", set the resolution of the laptop to "off"
- Put the laptop back below the desk, close the lid
- Now unlock the computer and use it normally.

Needless to say, it's quite annoying. The fact that with active VGA connection BIOS output goes straight to external monitor bypassing laptop's is even more annoying, because after kdm launches it switches back.

I don't want to save this configuration to xorg.conf because when I launch my laptop without external monitor I want it to work as expected.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!